# "window is not defined" with nuxtjs. Trying to build pages with generate

Tags: window, nuxt.js

I get the error message "window is not defined" if I use "window" in my default.vue template inside layouts folder. Building static pages with  "npm run generate" creates the error message. Mode is set to "universal"

```
...
created() {
  window.addEventlistener('scroll', e => {
    console.log('scrollleeed')
 })
}
...
```

What I'm doing wrong? I thought "generate" will create static pages and everything will be executed on the client side.

**Solution**
I have to use the mounted hook, not created for window or document related stuff

Answer (score 1):

generate will render pages on server, but only once e.g. at build time. But still to create static pages you need to render them on server, and hence that error

To avoid it you need to use window inside mounted, or wrap it with if (process.client) {}

Comment: Hmm my understanding of "generate" is that everything gets prerendered local and I have only to upload it on the server. So nothing have to be rendered on the server.  What do I understand wrong?

Comment: @GregorOi its right understanding. But you are missing one point, maybe i explained bad. It is prerendered locally, but locally its prerednered via same server rendering. So it will fail on prerender because u have window

Comment: ok found the solution, I have to put everything related with window or document inside mounted not created hook

Comment: @GregorOi yes, thats right. Mounted executed only on client. Another option is to wrap with if (process.client) {}

Comment: @Aldarund i have window use wrapped with if process.client but it still fails generate command with "window is not defined". Any ideas?